# SonarQube 5.6.6 - Failed to create working path

Tags: sonarqube

I recently updated to sonarqube 5.6.6(Oracle DB) from 5.1(MySQL). The Sonarqube instance is up but my jenkins builds are failing with below error. i have checked and all the permissions are in place. Any pointers would be appreciated

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.******source.scanner.maven:******-maven-plugin:3.2:****** (default-cli) on project XXXXXXXX: Unable to load component class org.******.core.platform.PluginLoader: Unable to load component class org.******.core.platform.PluginClassloaderFactory: Unable to load component interface org.******.api.utils.TempFolder: Failed to create working path: /home/abc/.****** -> [Help 1]

Comment: The user who is executing SonarQube must have r/w rights on the working path.

Comment: Thanks.. I have checked all user permissions and it seems to be in place.